# Cascading filter out bad records in a file

Tags: hdfs, etl, cascading

I am using Custom Functions for DQ checks in Cascading where I am setting an indicator based on which I will filter out the records at last into required pipes

I have written two functions for it. In the below code, Field 'A' is a String for which Null check needs to be done and Field 'B' is the code for which Decimal Check needs to be done. The indicator 'Ind' is set based on the Quality check result and it is passed into and set inside the functions IndicatorNull/IndicatorDecimal.

But I am facing an error in this code. I am not able to pass fields 'A' / 'Ind' and fields 'B'/'Ind' to the first and second filter of the same pipe.

Am I missing something here? Please let me know how this can be handled. Thanks!

Below is the portion of the code -

```
       Scheme inscheme = new TextDelimited(new Fields("A","B","Ind"),",");

        Tap sourceTap = new Hfs(inscheme, infile);
        Tap sinkTap = new Hfs(inscheme, outfile);

        Pipe BooleanPipe = new Pipe ("BooleanPipe");

        Fields findreturnNull = new Fields( "A","Ind" );
        Fields findreturnDecimal = new Fields("B", "Ind" );

        BooleanPipe = new Each( BooleanPipe, findreturnNull, new    
IndicatorNull(findreturnNull), Fields.RESULTS );
        BooleanPipe = new Each( BooleanPipe, findreturnDecimal, new IndicatorDecimal(findreturnDecimal), Fields.RESULTS );
```

Below is the error that I am getting -

```
Exception in thread "main" cascading.flow.planner.PlannerException: could not build flow from assembly: [[BooleanPipe][first.Boolean.main(Boolean.java:48)] unable to resolve argument selector: [{2}:'B', 'Ind'], with incoming: [{2}:'A', 'Ind']]
    at cascading.flow.planner.FlowPlanner.handleExceptionDuringPlanning(FlowPlanner.java:577)
    at cascading.flow.hadoop.planner.HadoopPlanner.buildFlow(HadoopPlanner.java:286)
    at cascading.flow.hadoop.planner.HadoopPlanner.buildFlow(HadoopPlanner.java:80)
    at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:459)
    at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:450)
    at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:426)
    at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:275)
    at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:220)
    at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:202)
    at first.Boolean.main(Boolean.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `Fields.RESULTS` parameter.

If you look at the flow:

```
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| Command  | Incoming Fields | Outgoing Fields | Reason                                   |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
|  Input   | "A", "B", "Ind" | "A", "B", "Ind" | Input, TextDelimited                     |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| 1st Each | "A", "B", "Ind" |    "A", "Ind"   | Fields.RESULTS will push only Results    | 
|          |                 |                 | fields. Rest will be discarded.          |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| 2nd Each |    "A", "Ind"   |      ERROR      | IndicatorDecimal() is looking from Field |
|          |                 |                 | "B" and it does not exists in Pipe.      |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
```

As you have both input & output fields same, the solution will be `Fields.REPLACE`.

Reference: [Fields Sets](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.5/userguide/html/ch03s07.html)